# toString undefined in app.js main file - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I am trying to get the filename of the uploaded file but I am getting error while doing string manipulation like below in main app file of nodejs:

```
var fileName = file.split('path:')[1]
    .split('\',')[0]
    .split(dir)[1]
    .toString()
    .replace(/\\/g, '')
    .replace(/\//g, '');
```

I get error at `.toString()`, not sure why.

## error stacktrace

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at C:\Users\murli\NodeProjects\SpeechExpress\app.js:57:76
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (C:\Users\murli\NodeProjects\SpeechExpress\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:105:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (C:\Users\murli\NodeProjects\SpeechExpress\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:553:8)
    at C:\Users\murli\NodeProjects\SpeechExpress\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:230:12
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\murli\NodeProjects\SpeechExpress\node_modules\formidable\lib\file.js:74:5)
    at WriteStream.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
```

## code

```
app.use('/uploadFile', function(request, response){

     // parse a file upload
    var mime = require('mime');
    var formidable = require('formidable');
    var util = require('util');

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    var dir = !!process.platform.match(/^win/) ? '\\public\\uploads\\' : '/public/uploads/';

    form.uploadDir = __dirname + dir;
    console.log("Test 99: " + form.uploadDir);
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    form.maxFields = 1000;
    form.multiples = false;
    console.log("Test 100: ");

    form.parse(request, function(err, fields, files) {

        var file = util.inspect(files);
        console.log("form parse file: "+file + "\n" + files);

        response.writeHead(200, getHeaders('Content-Type', 'application/json'));


        var fileName = file.split('path:')[1].split('\',')[0].split(dir)[1].toString().replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/\//g, '');
        var fileURL = 'http://' + app.address + ':' + port + '/public/uploads/' + fileName;

        console.log('fileURL: ', fileURL);

        response.write(JSON.stringify({
            fileURL: fileURL
        }));

        response.end();
    });

});
```

## file contents

```
{ file:
   File {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     size: 114898,
     path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm',
     name: '1234.webm',
     type: 'video/webm',
     hash: null,
     lastModifiedDate: 2017-09-19T22:18:03.330Z,
     _writeStream:
      WriteStream {
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm',
        fd: null,
        flags: 'w',
        mode: 438,
        start: undefined,
        autoClose: true,
        pos: undefined,
        bytesWritten: 114898,
        closed: true } } }
```

All I need is this

`upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm`

from this

`C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm`

Comment: Without knowing that `file` looks like, it's difficult to give the right suggestion

Comment: @Rowland its a video file of type webm. does that help? let me update my question with contents of file.

Comment: It means `.split(dir)[1]` isn't a string, you should check (console.log) if `split(dir)` is splitting the string properly

Comment: @Rowland I have uploaded the contents of the file. and I have highlighted what I am really interested in. Can someone tell me how to pull the part of the text (here the filename) I am interested in?

Comment: Why are you even converting to a string..??? and then parsing, why not just access the properties..

Comment: what is 'dir' ?

Comment: @jetblack I am really sorry, I will update my question with entire method

Comment: @jetblack I have added entire method which tells what dir holds.

Comment: You need to get on your RegEx game, brother! `(?!.*\\)(.*)\.webm` Should grab what you want. Give it a shot https://regex101.com/r/doguoS/1!

Comment: @Keith look at the file content  I need to convert this `C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm`  to `http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm` . Can you show your way of doing this?

Comment: Your using node so to get the filename use `path.basename()`, to get the filename in the first place, just access the object eg. `files.path`, or if it's an array it might be `files[0].path`.. Your currently convert an easy to parse object literal into a string, and then parsing..  So something like  `path.basename(files[0].path)`

Comment: A quick test of formidable in your case it would just be   `path.basename(files.file.path)`  No, regex, no parsing of strings.  Just use a nice object literal that formidable has given you.

Comment: @Keith You deserve correct answer. if you post the answer I can accept it

Comment: Ok, posted an answer.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 2 problems to this question.

The first is how can you extract the filename from a full directory string.  Because your using node.js, it comes with a handy function `path.basename(filename)`.

The second problem, is how to get the path in the first place.
Formidable supplies the files, this is a simple object literal with all the files,.  Your file input name appears to be called file,.. So to access the path, you can just do `files.file.path`.

So after combining both of these we have.. `path.basename(files.file.path)`, you should get your filename, in this case been -> `upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm`

Answer (score 1):

What not save yourself the headache just use `path.basename`?

[From the docs:](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext)

```
var path = require('path');

path.basename('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html');
// Returns: 'quux.html'

path.basename('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html', '.html');
// Returns: 'quux'
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
var f = File.path.split('\\');
var fileName = f[f.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

> All I need is this
>
> `upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm`
>
> from this
>
> `C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm`

then simply:

```
let path = 'C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm',
    filename = path.split('\\').pop();
```

and replace `path` with the correct reference

Comment: but I still need to get this first : C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm  which is inside File object like I showed in file contents above. do I do path.basename() then on that your answer. also actually it needs to be relative so : http://localhost:3000/public/.../filename.webm

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you use Regex to handle it.

E:G

```
let file = 'C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm'
let fileName = file.match(/upload_\w+.webm$/)[0];
let fileURL = 'http://' + app.address + ':' + port + '/public/uploads/' + fileName;

// ....The rest of the code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use node, so I would advise you to use the official path object:

```js
const path = require("path")

const myFileName = "C:\\Users\\username\\NodeProjects\\SpeechExpress\\public\\uploads\\upload_3c927e85105d0fd5d873e84952821531.webm"
const unixFile = "/home/test/jhgfd.h"
const obj = path.parse(myFileName)
console.log(obj.name)
console.log(obj)
```

The best is that it will also work on Linux. The attribute you want is called name.